# How to serialize/deserialize YAML::Binary?

Tags: yaml-cpp

## UPDATE

*It now seems that anything put in a vector breaks. I have tried char and u/int/8/16/32 and they all generate some kind of error. I'm a bit perplexed. There may be an error in my code, but I'm not sure what the YAML should look like, so I'm probably not doing a very a very good job of looking for when the data becomes incorrect.*

Is YAML::Binary from Yaml-Cpp finished yet? I've tried serializing my data as int's, but Yaml-Cpp seems to be confused about ints and chars, and this generally never works. Instead, now I'm trying to use Yaml::Binary, but I get an error on the other side when I try to recover the YAML::Binary node on the other end. Specifically, this chunk fails:

3: 0\n6: 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\n7: /USER_NAMES/src/sockets/rsc/atkrscs.tar.gz\n1: 0\n4: 0\n5: 651633\n2: 0

As:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::ParserException'
  what():  yaml-cpp: error at line 7, column 7: unknown escape character:`

What should I do? Is there another way to send/receive binary? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Could you post (a) some code, and (b) the exact YAML you're trying to parse? It's hard to try to guess at what's going on here. (In particular, your YAML has some `\n` listed: I assume those are newlines? Can you make them newlines in your post?)

Comment: This is going to be difficult. It's a somewhat complex program, and I'm transfering a large file. I will see how much of it I can put up somewhere.

Comment: Try to make a minimal example. You don't need to post your entire program - just the snippet that loads the piece you want. Ideally, you'd make a standalone program the still exhibits the behavior you're seeing. See http://sscce.org

Comment: I made the smallest example I could. It's not that simple, and it's also not quite what my program did before. It's 11 here and I've been working all day, so I may have done something silly in it that I didn't do in my real work. My project is available from [link](https://spideroak.com/browse/share/valpublic/public/_publicspider/)

I put the example YAML as "FirstSegment.txt" .

Comment: I think what's going on in your example is that you're writing the `vector<char>` to `SerialFile[2]`, but then you're trying to read it from `Deserial`; if you read it from `Deserial[2]`, it should work properly.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with `YAML::Binary`, which you're not using; you're just reading/writing a `vector<char>`.

Comment: 1. The example was not using Binary, but my project did. As I said at first, I've tried using different methods of representing my data. 2. I am respecting indexes in my actual project. Since I have been able to get the shorter example to work, I assume the problem is still me, though. All I can do at this point is keep debugging it and try to find out what's going wrong. Thanks again for looking into this.